# Analytics - Where do my drop offs go?

Tags: google-analytics, click-tracking

I have a website set up with Google Analytics (through the Wordpress plugin "Google Analytics for WordPress" by Yoast).

When I check out the visitors flow in Google Analytics, it shows something like this:

```
(home) - 43% drop-offs 
/page-2/ - 10% drop-offs 
... etc ...
```

I have also set up events for external links. My main "goal" of the website is to drive traffic to my Android app on Google Play, so I have a couple of different links to that that are all set up as events. Everything seems to be working, my events show up when I go to Content -> Events in Google Analytics.

However, it seems to me that some percentage of the users that are reported as "drop-offs" in fact have clicked on one of the external links. But there's no info about the reason of those drop-offs in the Visitors flow-chart. I can of course check out each specific event category, event action and set "other" to Content/Page, which  (I guess) shows the number of visitors who triggered a specific event on a specific page. It just seems like such a complicated way of going about this!

So, is there a way to get a more detailed picture, including events, in the Visitors flow chart?

Something like:

```
(home) - 43% drop-offs 
           Event Action: "Google Play"=50%, "Youtube"=10%, (not set)=40%
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this:
http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already tracking events. What I'm asking for is a way to display the reason for "drop-offs" as Google Analytics call them, i.e. the reason people leave my site, be it through an external link (event) or just closing their browser window or whatever. I guess now that I think about it, it doesn't seem very likely to to - Google doesn't have a particular event type for navigating-away-from-my-website-events, just plain text event category, action and label. And an event is certainly not restricted to beeing an outbound link...